# how do I setblock a repeating chain command block? | Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a one command creation and I need to know to do this HELP!

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried?  Show your work!  That will help us, and you, quite a bit.  That said, if you're just going to call me names, I won't bother trying to help anymore.

Comment: a repeating chain cmd block? there are only repeating or chain cmd blocks. However, try using FallingSand in combination with passengers

Comment: @Smart_Snake I don't even understand what ur asking.

Answer (score 3):

I really don't know about the setblock command but a repeating command block can be given with commands as repeating_command_block. You'll need a redstone block or redstone torch adjacent to the command block when it spawns so it can get power.
So, like:

```
/setblock x y z minecraft:repeating_command_block
```

And then have a redstone block right next to the actual coordinate.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a 'repeating chain command block', whatever *that* entails. What you seem to want to do is place a repeating one adjacent to a chain one. Then, if there is no command in the repeating one, you use it to create starting impulses for the chain one. Thus, you get a chain command block that repeats its command every 20 t/sec, which is what I understand to be what you need. Not sure as to why you'd need something like that, though.